# Why do I need another iterator as an argument in std::copy()?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I don't understand why I need to put another iterator as the second argument in the call to `std::copy()` for reading through a file. How is iterator 'end' ending of a file?

```cpp
    vector<Point> v;
    istream_iterator<Point> is(file), end;
    copy(is, end, back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: A range needs to points: The beginning and the end. If you don't have an end, how would `std::copy` know when to stop copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is iterator 'end' ending of a file?

By convention and/or a design decision in the standard library. The iterator `end` is default-constructed, and on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator), we learn about the default `std:istream_iterator` constructor:

> ```
> constexpr istream_iterator();
> ```
>
> Constructs the end-of-stream iterator, value-initializes the stored value [...]

The deeper reasoning is that the standard algorithms are built around the concept of a half-open range, often denoted as `[first, last)`. The `is` iterator must be distinguished from some kind of end sentinel `last` - otherwise, `std::copy` can't know when reading from the input is not meaningful anymore (i.e., when it has reached the end of the file). In your case, this is `end`.

Comment: So in other words, it just needs another iterator as a comparison?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the example implementation of [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy): the main loop compares `first` to `last`, where `last` is your `end`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

You need to tell the algorithm somehow how many elements it should copy. Note that `copy` is generic and the reason to use iterators is to be agnostic of the actual container. Hence, the algorithm has no way to stop when it reaches the end of the container. All it has is the two iterators you pass it.

**How?**

This is just how it is defined in the language. If you look at the constructor that takes no arguments you see that it creates a special end-of-stream iterator. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator):

> ```
> constexpr istream_iterator();    (1)
> ```
>
> 1) Constructs the end-of-stream iterator, value-initializes the stored value. This constructor is constexpr if the initializer in the definition auto x = T(); is a constant initializer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is asking why `std::copy` doesn't just stop copying when it encounters an actual `EOF` (end-of-file) character in the file rather than the contrived method of passing in a default-constructed iterator.

`std::copy` is a generic algorithm that works on many containers that have iterators. Copying from vectors or arrays requires both start and end input iterators, since in vectors and arrays there are no corresponding EOF markers. Since we want to use the same `copy` program for files, file iterators are intended *just* for this purpose, and the implementation likely does something like

> if the file iterator points to `EOF`, then set it to the default constructed value

which is of course trivial to implement. Of course, it *is* possible to have a function called like `file_copy(file, destination)`, but then it would be a different interface from the *standard* `std::copy` that we are used to, and we would be using a different `copy` function for files as we do for arrays and vectors.